# Render different view if no param is provided

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I want to match two URLs in my Vue app, `/users`, and `/users/:id`. For `/users`, it displays a table with a list of users, and `/users/:id` displays the profile page for that single user.

I know I can do it like this:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    name: 'View Users',
    component: UserList
},
{
    path: 'users/:id',
    name: 'User Profile',
    component: UserProfile
}
```

However, I automatically generate breadcrumbs from the route path. By doing it as above, the user profile page isn't shown as a subpage of the user list (e.g. it shows `Home / User Profile` rather than `Home / View Users / User Profile`).

I've tried it as follows:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    name: 'View Users',
    component: UserList,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            name: 'User Profile',
            component: UserProfile
        }
    ]
}
```

This solves my breadcrumb issue, however as `UserList` doesn't have a `<router-view>` tag, all that is rendered is the same `UserList` view, rather than the profile view.

The docs aren't massively helpful (https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you need to put both UserList and UserProfile in the children list. Have `users` redirect to `users/list`.

Comment: That doesn't solve the breadcrumb issue, which requires the profile component to be a child of the list component

Comment: But the profile component is not a child of the list component in the sense that the docs give children. A child appears as a subunit on a parent's page.